# How to retain value of the set()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

```
current_values=set(["guy","guy1", "guy3"])

def remove_stale_values(previous_values, current_values):
    todelete = previous_values - current_values
    previous_values.clear()
    for elements in current_values:
        previous_values.add(elements)

    for value in todelete:
       #do something
       print "done"

def m(previous_values, current_values):
    remove_stale_values(previous_values, current_values)

m(set(), current_values)
```

wrote this function to store the current_values into previous_values so that when second time this func runs ,I am expecting to get the difference between previous and current values.But every time this function runs  previous_values get set to [].

Basically I want to save the previous_values and when second time I run this function then I get the difference of two values.

```
 todelete = previous_values - current_values
```

Comment: Fix your indentation? Is the last line supposed to be a recursive call inside the function?

Comment: What are `previous_metrics` and `current_metrics`? Should those be `previous_values` and `current_values`?

Comment: The previous set is an empty set. So when you subtract from it, you get another empty set in `todelete`.

Comment: `def m(set(), current_values):` makes no sense. You don't put a function call in the parameter list.

Comment: The call `m()` is missing the arguments.

Comment: This code is just a total mess. You need to post the actual code that doesn't get syntax errors.

Comment: @Barmar apologies I fixed the code.Yea first time this func runs previous _values will going to be empty but as you probably notice I am appending current_values in previous_values.But when i run it second time it's value get reset

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. What is your expected output? What are you getting? What is different? Be *explicit*.

Comment: "But every time this function runs previous-values get set to []." -> please show the actual code; what you were expecting; and what you got instead.

Comment: Um, do you call it like this: `m(set(), current_values)` a second time?

Comment: You're not saving the updated `previous_values` anywhere, so how do you expect it to be used the second time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a variable to hold `previous_values`, so the updated value can be reused.

```
previous_values = set()
m(previous_values, current_values)
# do stuff
m(previous_values, current_values)
```